# cropping a photo using css

Tags: html, css

I need to crop quadrilateral for a photo. I need parallelogram. But it is skewed. I need a parallelogram crop. How can I do it?

Code is below:

```css
img {
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  position:relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/RL%20Gang%20Boy.jpg">
```

What i want is i dont want boy to turn sideways but only the picture to crop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `svg`'s `clipPath` and `foreignObject` to apply inline `clip-path` for [maximum browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

```html
<svg width="300" height="400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="parallelogram">
      <path d="M50,0 h250 l-50,400 h-250z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#parallelogram)" width="100%" height="100%">
    <img src="http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/RL%20Gang%20Boy.jpg" />
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your's works somehow. I don't know how to use svg but thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

please try this css + html script

### CSS

```
#graphic {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
}

#graphic:before { 
content: '';    
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
z-index: -1;

background-image: url(http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/RL%20Gang%20Boy.jpg`enter code here`); /* Image is 500px by 500px, but only 200px        by 50px is showing. */
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="graphic">lorem ipsum</div>
```